# Ошибка при создании базы данных HSQL: database alias does not exist

Tags: java, база-данных

Необходимо подключить проект Maven (на Eclipse) к HSQL.
Подскажите, правильная ли это команда для создания базы данных?

runServer.bat --database.0 mem:mydb --dbname.0 workdb

Команду вписываю в cmd, предварительно перейдя в каталог, где лежит runServer.bat.

При открытии runManagerSwing и прописке URL: jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/workdb, выдает ошибку: database alias does not exist. То есть база не создана, как я понимаю. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

скачиваете архив с https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/

правите файл server.properties

```
server.database.0=hsqldbtest
server.dbname.0=hsqldbtest
server.port=2004
```

из папки bin запускаете runServer.bat

подключение

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:2004/hsqldbtest","SA","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на стартовые логи сервера (ниже).
Найдите слово alias=. По умолчанию у меня "xdb".
Используете в URL этот алиас для соединения.

jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb

Например,

[Server@5b2133b1]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method

[Server@5b2133b1]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:mydb, alias=**xdb**] opened successfully in 407 ms.

[Server@5b2133b1]: Startup sequence completed in 412 ms.

[Server@5b2133b1]: 2019-02-28 22:00:06.776 HSQLDB server 2.4.1 is online on port 9001

[Server@5b2133b1]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL

[Server@5b2133b1]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly